# Issue with Perl script and Apache2.2

Tags: cgi-bin

we have a perl script which is used to call 404 error when file is not present on Apache webserver , this is working fine . But it is failing when it is called inside the folder(cgi-bin) were is script is located.

for eg  www.site.com/cgi-bin/test (this should invoke 404 but instead of 404 error this prints below error which is displayed on browser).

h1>Software error:

```
slurp_filename('/cgi-bin/t') / opening: (2) No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/ModPerl/RegistryCooker.pm line 541
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the error by changing :

```
#SetHandler perl-script
#PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
```

to :

```
SetHandler cgi-script
PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
```